# RegEx matches more than I was bargaining for

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have this regex: `CMD?(S?[1-8][0-1]|R?[1-8]|[qQ])`

It should match these cases:

All cases should start with "CMD"

followed by either:

1. 'S' followed by

   1. [1-8] followed by
   2. [0-1]
2. 'R' followed by

   1. [1-8]
3. 'q' or 'Q'

but I find it also matches `CMD[1-8][1-0]` I can't figure what I am doing wrong.

And finaly, what should I do to get a regex match all but these cases, cause I cant find a solution to negate the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the meaning of `?`, which actually means "0 or 1 of the preceding character." That's why you're getting matches without the `S`.

The regex you're looking for is:

```
CMD(S[1-8][01]|R[1-8]|[qQ])
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I missed the second half of your question.

It depends on what implementation you're using. For example, in Perl, it's as easy as writing `!~` instead of `=~`. Otherwise, you can use what's called a "negative lookahead assertion." Assuming you still want the negated series to begin with a `CMD`:

```
CMD(?!S[1-8][01]|R[1-8]|[qQ])
```

Comment: That, solved the fist problem - Thanks! - but I still need to negate the whole expression, which would make it match all but that RegEx

Comment: And if the negated series shouldn't start with CMD, cause that might more be the case

Comment: Well, then it becomes an ill-defined problem. You need additional constraints. What exactly counts as the negation? Technically isn't an empty string a match for the negation? Basically, any gibberish of any length can be considered a match. You have to be more specific, like say, "4 letters followed by 0, 1, or 2 numbers, but not in the CMD format mentioned."

Comment: Ok, I can see the problem, I just thought that if one could make a RegEx that would match a certain group of strings, one would be able to negate it which would make a RegEx matching any group of strings not matching the previous expression.